# MDbgProcess WaitHandle not receiving signals from w3wp

Tags: w3wp, mdbg

In trying to construct a managed debugger in C#, we are using the code from `Microsoft.Samples.Debugging.MdbgEngine`.  The `WaitHandle` for our `MDbgProcess` receives signals from the underlying process just fine for console apps, winform apps, and IIS hosted ASP.Net apps on localhost.  Once we move the target application, specifically the IIS hosted ASP.Net app to a server 2008 and 2012 OS, the WaitHandle stops receiving signals.  We've tried lots of debugging steps, including but not limited to:

- Copying dev builds of the application onto the server
- Building debugger and target against

  - AnyCPU
  - x86
  - x64
- Layering in exhaustive diagnostic messaging
- Installing Visual Studio on the server and building everything there
- Trying different app pools and different app pool settings

Has anyone ever used these components for ASP.Net on a server OS or have any ideas what might be going on?

https://github.com/SymbolSource/Microsoft.Samples.Debugging

thx